# How to make an envif host count subdomains

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I use this to require password, but only on my dev site:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.website\.com$ require_auth=true
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/website.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

The problem is that there are various other subdomains that I also want password protected that are very similar. How can I make it so:

- medev.website.com
- devdev.website.com
- testdev.website.com

Or anything else that starts with "[***]dev." needs a password I know it's a regex thing but it's just not something I understand well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetEnvIf` accepts a regex so you can use:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^.*dev\.website\.com$ require_auth=true
```